# How to get the data from the database created by another activity/ Fails to update data into database (Android studio,SQLite)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Thanks to **Midhun MP**, these 2 problems are solved! And I have a new question: I have 2 String to take over the data, one from what I entered, one from the database, I use the fonction equals() to make the comparison but they won't match, even though they are same numbers to me... I update below:

```
public void buttonOpen(View view) {
    EditText txtpass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  //on recuperer le mot de passeword
    String pass1str = txtpass1.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(ParCode.this, pass1str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//test

    Cursor allCode = new DataCode(this).getCode();//get the data from database using Cursor
    allCode.moveToFirst();
    while (!allCode.isAfterLast())
    {
        String code = allCode.getString(0);
        Log.i(code, "Code");
        allCode.moveToNext();
    }
    String pass2str = allCode.toString();//le data dans le bibliotheque

    if (pass1str.equals(pass2str)) {...}
```

Is the problem of the type of data?

---

Hello,guys. I'm a newb and my android-studio program is driving me crazy.
 
It's kind like a login program, I have 2 activities: **The first one** is for users to enter their password, I think it needs to get what user has entered and compare with the data in the database; **The second one** is for users to change password, I think this means update the data in the database
I've used sqlite to build a database for the code.(right now there is only one column for just one code but further there may be different users)

---

Here is my question: 
1. According to my emulator, I can insert data into database, but fail to update it. Which is weird because when I click the update button, it tells me the code has been changed. 
2. I need my first activity to get the code (which is saved in the database created by the second activity), and compare with what user has entered. But I don't know how to do this...
My database code:

```
public class DataCode extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Code4.dp";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Code_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "CODE";//a une seule ligne

public DataCode(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (CODE TEXT )");//create the table
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

//insert data
public boolean insertData(String CODE) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();//insert to database
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, CODE);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

//show data
public Cursor getCode(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);//store table in cursor
    return res;
}

//modifier code
public boolean updateCode(String CODE) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();//create database
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, CODE);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "code = ?", new String[]{ CODE });
    return true;
}
}
```

and my second activity's code (it fails to update the data):

```
public class ModifierC extends AppCompatActivity {
DataCode myDbC;//creat the database

EditText editCode;
Button Modifier;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modifier_c);

    myDbC = new DataCode(this);//my database for code

    editCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password2);
    Modifier = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMP);
    buttonMP();//modifier le code

}

public void buttonMP(){//button to change the password

    Modifier.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText txtpass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);

                    String pass2str = txtpass2.getText().toString();


                        Cursor res = myDbC.getCode();
                        if (res.getCount() == 0) {//if there is no data in the database, use the insert method
                            boolean isInserted = myDbC.insertData(editCode.getText().toString());
                            if (isInserted == true)
                                Toast.makeText(ModifierC.this, "Code enregistré", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(ModifierC.this, "Pas encore de code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        else {//if there is already a code, use the update method
                            boolean isUpdated = myDbC.updateCode(editCode.getText().toString());//recuperer le code de password2
                            if (isUpdated == true)
                                Toast.makeText(ModifierC.this, "Code a changé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(ModifierC.this, "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
    );
}
}
```

And for the first activity, I use Cursor to pass the data

```
public class ParCode extends AppCompatActivity {
DataCode myC;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_par_code);
}

public void buttonOpen(View view) {
    EditText txtpass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  //get what user has entered
    String pass1str = txtpass1.getText().toString();          

    Cursor coderes = myC.getCode();// search code in the database
    String pass2str = coderes.getString(0);
```

BUT it won't work, I think I may miss something.

---

Sorry this maybe a too long and very stupid question. However I have spend over one week on this, so I think I should ask for help. It's my first time to build an android app, and all my question is because of lacking of basic knowledge. But I really have to prepare for my test and have no time to stuck on this right now T T...So please give me some advice!!! 
THANKS A LOT

---

the logcat gives me this:

```
06-03 06:22:58.224 27801-27801/com.example.android.sacconnecte I/4444: Code
06-03 06:22:58.327 27801-27839/com.example.android.sacconnecte W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 06:22:58.327 27801-27839/com.example.android.sacconnecte W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79f0a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-03 06:23:08.396 27801-27839/com.example.android.sacconnecte E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab81b280
```

the first line is the code got from database. It works! just somehow it won't match with what I entered. Oh la la....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening because of the following line:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "code = ?", new String[]{ CODE });
```

Suppose your db consists of a value "Elsa", and now you are trying to update it to "Hello", the above code in sql query looks something similar to:

```
UPDATE Code_table SET CODE = 'Hello' WHERE code = 'Hello'
```

The above where clause will be false and the row won't be updated.

You need to use:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, null, null);
```

The third and fourth parameters represents the `WhereClause` and `WhereArgs`. In your case you don't need to specify those (Because you don't have any unique or primary key fields defined).

Now the query will look like:

```
UPDATE Code_table SET CODE = 'Hello'
```

---

For getting the result using cursor, you can use the following code:

```
Cursor allCode = new DataCode().getCode();

allCode.moveToFirst();

while (!allCode.isAfterLast())
{
    String code = allCode.getString(0);
    Log.i(code, "Code");
    allCode.moveToNext();

}
```

Comment: THAT WORKS!! Thank you so much! And the metaphor is really help me to understand~ Now I just have one problem to fix XD

Comment: I'm still stuck on the second question, could you please take a look at it too? I thought once a database is created any activity could use it by using Cursor, but it won't work :(

Comment: It didn't work...I can't paste my logcat here, I've updated it in the question page, could you please check it for me?

Comment: @Elsa: Can you check with `allCode.getString(1);` instead of `allCode.getString(0);` ?

Comment: it shows "Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns." and the Emulator shut down. Followed by a " E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main" and lots of things  :o

Comment: I'm sorry I think the cursor works, because, the "4444" which I thought was what I have entered, actually it is not, it's the code in the database, I think the app goes wrong because the app fails to get what I have entered...which is weird, it worked before = =!

Comment: But anyway you have perfectly solved my questions! Thanks for your patience and kindly help!!!!!